# Trouble understanding application/vnd.amundsen.maze+xml using wget

Tags: xml, api, rest, wget

im going over this [Maze tutorial](http://amundsen.com/media-types/maze/tutorial/#collection) and I'm learning about Restful API's.

In the resource of the link above it says "Clients can request a list of available mazes by sending an HTTP GET request to the server."

how do i get this list of available resources using wget. Im learning wget If there is a way of writing it in a text editor using js i would like to see how that is done too.

```
C:\path\practice\wget> wget -S -q http://www.example.org --header=" Content-Type : application/vnd.amundsen.maze+xml"
```

the windows cli says ::: wget: --header: Invalid header `Content-Type application/vnd.amundsen.maze+xml

can some show me a way to get this list of available mazes using wget. That would be very helpful. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove spaces before and after Content-Type. This will work:

```
wget -S -q http://www.example.org --header="Content-Type: application/vnd.amundsen.maze+xml"
```